# Import dart:html in Service got exception No provider found for dynamic

Tags: dependency-injection, angular-dart, dart-html

I have a working `UserService` similar to `HeroService` from AngularDart tutorial with `BrowserClient`.
And now I need to use `localStorage` to save the API response.

After I import `dart:html`, I refresh my browser, suddenly I got error on console:

```
EXCEPTION: No provider found for dynamic: UserService -> dynamic.
```

When I remove the import, the service running well.

this is my UserService code.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:http/http.dart';

import 'package:my_app/src/instance_logger.dart';

class UserService with InstanceLogger {
  static final _headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
  static const _authUrl = 'https://my.domain/api-token-auth/';
  String get loggerPrefix => 'UserService'; // or set ''

  final Client _http;

  UserService(this._http);

  dynamic _extractData(Response resp) => json.decode(resp.body)['data'];

  Exception _handleError(dynamic e) {
    log(e); // for demo purposes only
    return Exception('Server error; cause: $e');
  }
}
```

in Component meta-data:

```
  providers: [ClassProvider(UserService)],
```

how to use `dart:html` within service? If I want to access `localStorage`.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both dart:html and package:http/http.dart unfortunately have a class named `Client`.

How you get around this collision is to *hide* an unwanted class from being imported with its package.

Change

`import 'dart:html';`

to

`import 'dart:html' hide Client;`

That will take care of the collision.  You could alternatively give the import an alias such as:

`import 'dart:html' as html;`

Then you can use `localStorage` by using the prefix `html.localStorage`;

When I run into this problem I just hide the `Client` class from the dart:html import.

Comment: oh i just saw the same (related) answer on https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/issues/1847